# Getting the id of a menuitem

Tags: primefaces

How can I get the id of a menuitem when I click it? The following example doesn't work:

```
<p:panelMenu id="panelMenuId">
    <p:submenu id="submenuId" label="submenu">
        <p:menuitem id="menuitemId" 
                    action="/views/view" 
                    oncomplete="showId(this);" 
                    value="link_1" />
    </p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>

function showId(menuitemComponent) {
    alert(menuitemComponent.id);
}
```

This is an SSCCE, I really execute an ajax request and I need the oncomplete event because I need to execute something using ajax and then do something with the id of the menuitem with jQuery after the ajax request finished.

Comment: I tested in onclick and it didn't work. It shows a blank alert

Comment: Is it your first time in primefaces.
p:menuItem has an equivalent in HTML elements.

Ex : <p:outputText value="Test"/> :  <span>Test</span>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get id from p:menuitem you can inspect the element from developer tool of browsers
After that you can use jquery to grap element.

Also you can try onclick it is better from oncomplete, because you are not sending ajax request so no need to wait complete of ajax request.

onclick will be trigger when you click the menuitem.

Comment: My question has an SSCCE, I really execute an ajax request and I need the oncomplete event because I need to execute something using ajax and then do something with the id of the menuitem with jQuery after the ajax request finished

Comment: did you checked in browser's developer tool?

Comment: if it is <input onclick='showId(this)'/>
then i am sure it will work but in primefaces you need to check in browser developer tool to be sure about javascript